# MS Teams tab app | stop reloading MS Teams tab app on each time we visit a tab

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We are building an MS Teams Tab app in React JS that contains a list of users in a team. Once we install the app in a team and try to switch between tabs, then our tab reloads every time we click on it. Due to reloading, we are losing the state of the Tab view (For e.g., the sorting or filtering applied on the user list).
Is it possible to not load the tab on every click and maintain the same view?

Do we have mechanism using which we can maintain same view on clicking on it? Currently, If I go to tab, it reloads and act as first time we clicked on it.

I see the loading first on selecting tab then after few seconds my tab loads. Wish to improve the performance pf the tab loading.

Thank you for helping in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**"This is by design behavior."**

To workaround this issue, you can make your tab as static so it will be loaded once and then cached by Teams.

When building a tab for your Teams app, you have the option to make it static. A static tab is loaded once and then cached by Teams, which means that the content of the tab will not be reloaded every time the user navigates to it. This can help improve the performance and user experience of your app.

Ref Doc:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#statictabs
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-personal-tab?tabs=vs&pivots=node-java-script

Comment: Thank You for your response. But we are adding tab to a channel. Static tabs declared in personal scope are always pinned to the app's personal experience. Static tabs declared in the team scope are currently not supported. Is there anything that we can do for team scope tab?

Comment: For team scope tabs, you can use configurable tabs. Configurable tabs allow users to configure the tab when adding it to a channel.
To maintain the same view without loading the configurable tab on every click, you can use the canUpdateConfiguration property in your manifest.json file. This property takes a Boolean value that indicates whether a user can modify or reconfigure the tab after it's created.

Comment: Ref Docs: 1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-channel-group-tab?tabs=vs&pivots=blazor-app
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/configuration-page?tabs=teamsjs-v2
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#configurabletabs

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT I have a static tab with an external url configured at contentUrl pointing to a SPA website but each time I access to the tab It loads the entire site again. Any suggestion?